# Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first

Tags: c#, wpf, frameworkelement

here is the error I have when I want to attach a FrameworkElement to a new Window to publish it to a PNG file.

So my idea is to remove the parent-child link, call my method, and add the child again with this code :

```
this.RemoveLogicalChild(element);
PublishFrameworkElement(element, stream);
this.AddLogicalChild(element);
```

But I got the exact same error...

I looked a lot of questions about this error, here on SO, but none answered to my problem
What am I missing ?

EDIT : here is the code that worked for me :

```
var element = _GeneratedContent as FrameworkElement;
var ParentPanelCollection = (element.Parent as Panel).Children as UIElementCollection;
ParentPanelCollection.Clear();

FileStream stream = [...]

if (element != null)
{
    PublishFrameworkElement(element, stream);
    ParentPanelCollection.Add(element);
}
stream.Close();
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If `element` is the child of a Panel (e.g. Grid) you have to remove it from the Panel's [Children](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.children.aspx) collection. If it is set as `Content` of a `ContentControl`, you'd have to set that Content to null (or anything else that is not `element`).

Comment: would setting to null, disconnect events as well ?

Comment: No, you would also have to remove any event handlers.

Comment: Additionally: if you have a `Decorator` like `Border` you can simply set it's `Child=null`

Answer (score 6):

Guillaume,

You can try to additionally use **RemoveVisualChild** method after **RemoveLogicalChild**:

```
this.RemoveLogicalChild(element);
this.RemoveVisualChild(element);
PublishFrameworkElement(element, stream);
```

Hope this helps,
Piotr.

Comment: I tried it before but this give me this error : "Specified Visual is not a child of this Visual."

Comment: Guillaume, the code I've posted doesn't throw this exception, so maybe you're using it in a different context. Please post some more code and describe your problem with more detail so it's easier for us to help you.

Comment: Additionally, what is "this" in your case?

Answer (score 3):

Old question but I didn't have luck with the other answers, so I made a extension method to remove the item from its parent.

```
public static class FrameworkElementHelper
{
    public static void RemoveFromParent(this FrameworkElement item)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            var parentItemsControl = (ItemsControl)item.Parent;
            if (parentItemsControl != null)
            {
                parentItemsControl.Items.Remove(item as UIElement);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: > **Usage Note:** change ( **ItemsControl** ) to the type of ( **Element parent** ) you have, for example if you have **`< StackPanel />`**  then change it to (**StackPanel**) ,  and changed `Items.Remove` to `Children.Remove` in the case of (StackPanel) .  and so on, Apply any changes that fit the Element parent of your choice if needed

Answer (score 1):

I had similar but slightly different issue but got the same error message. I made a workaround by making an inherited class and calling RemoveLogicalChild (since this is a protected method).

```
 public partial class PopupWindow : Window
{
    public PopupWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClosed(e);
        this.RemoveLogicalChild(this.Content);    // since protected method
    }
}
```

It worked for me. I made a simple example you can see here.

http://wpfgrid.blogspot.com/2013/01/wpf-error-specified-element-is-already.html